# Where did I err in using a public data?

Tags: sql, concatenation

I was reviewing the use of CONCAT using a public data I had earlier used while following a lecture. However, the data returned "null" results during this particular review so I could not proceed with my query. Where did I err?

I simply followed the same procedure as in the lecture, so I was expecting the same result in which I can practice CONCAT

Comment: Unless you post a code sample or a sql fiddle this is difficult to answer

Comment: Note that CONCAT is a product specific function. ANSI/ISO SQL has `||` as concatenation operator. E.g. `'abc' || 'def'` will give you `abcdef`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sql fiddle that achieves this using the concat and coalesce functions.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/128f61/4

Here is the SQL schema:

```
create table colors (first varchar(20), second varchar(20));
insert into colors (first, second) values
  ('red', 'blue'),
  ('red', 'green'),
  ('blue', 'yellow'),
  (NULL, 'red'),
  ('red', NULL);
```

Here is the select statement:

```
select concat(coalesce(first, ''), coalesce(second, '')) from colors;
```

According to w3schools the coalesce function returns "the first non-null value in a list". [1]

The concat and coalesce functions are included in SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, and many other relational database management systems (RDBMS).

---

Footnotes:

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp